# Yii2 Menu::Widget() How to make it static when scrolling

Tags: yii2, widget

Looking for a way to keep the menu static when scrolling down.  Any suggestions?

```
<div class="nav-wrapper" ><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo" style="margin-left:50px; top-margin:0px; bottom-margin:10px;"><img class="topleft" width="200px" height="50px" src='http://go2-telecom.com/resources/images/logo-nobackground-1000.png'></a>
        <?php
                    echo Menu::widget([
                        'options' => ['id' => "nav-mobile", 'class' => 'green lighten-1 right navbar-fixed-top'],
                        'items' => [
                            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
                            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['site/about']],
                            ['label' => 'Services', 'url' => ['site/services']],
                ['label' => 'Careers', 'url' => ['site/careers']],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['site/contact']],
                ['label' => 'Resumes', 'url' => ['resume/index'], 'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
                            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['site/login'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
                        ],
                    ]);
                ?>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming, you don't mean something like this? Specifically notice this class `navbar-fixed-top`.

```
<?php
NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
    'class' => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    'role' => 'navigation',
],
]);

$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['controller url here']],
];

 echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
```